# select from a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to fill up a list with structures I have in another list, but filtering the selection using one of the arguments(introduced by user, Type) of the structure and I can't seem to get the recursion right,help would be very much appreciated.

```
selectOmnibus([],_,[]).
selectOmnibus([H|T],Type,[O|R]):-
        member(O,[H|T]),
    O = omnibus(Type,_,_,_,_),
    selectOmnibus(T,Type,R).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. Your base case is fine. Since you're doing the recursion manually, you don't need to use `member/2`. You're also missing the other inductive case, which is where `O` doesn't match the structure type.

```
selectOmnibus([], _, []).
selectOmnibus([O|T], Type, Result) :-
  O = omnibus(Type,_,_,_,_) 
    -> (selectOmnibus(T,Type,R), Result = [O|R])
    ;   selectOmnibus(T, Type, Result).
```

Try that. If it's not right, it would help to see a sample input and output.

**Edit**: you can separate the clauses like this:

```
selectOmnibus([], _, []).
selectOmnibus([O|T], Type, [O|R]) :-
  O = omnibus(Type,_,_,_,_), 
  selectOmnibus(T,Type,R).
selectOmnibus([O|T], Type, R) :-
  O \= omnibus(Type,_,_,_,_), 
  selectOmnibus(T,Type,R).
```

Note that you have to repeat the test inverted. You can add a cut to make it more efficient, but you have to repeat the inverse test or you won't have "backwards correctness" because it will be possible to enter the third clause by backtracking and there won't be anything there to ensure that you aren't discarding legitimate omnibuses.

Comment: one more thing, would it be ok to replace -> for the ,??

Comment: that only if i separate the clause in two ways, one if O unifies, the other otherwise.
    selectOmnibus([], _, []).
selectOmnibus([O|T], Type, Result) :-
  O = omnibus(Type,_,_,_,_)
    , (selectOmnibus(T,Type,R), Result = [O|R]).

selectOmnibus([O|T], Type, Result) :-
  O \= omnibus(Type,_,_,_,_)
  , selectOmnibus(T, Type, Result).

Comment: and what do you use Result for now??